# Express + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to connect an application to mongoDB with express, for the moment i have no problem with the collection users, it works perfectly but it doesn't work for my second collection, when i try to get all data of my second collection, express return me a empty array.

```
// Import dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// MongoDB URL from the docker-compose file
const dbHost = 'mongodb://database/mybase';

// Connect to data
mongoose.connect(dbHost);

// create mongoose schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    mail: String,
    mdp: String,
    firstname: String,
    participants: Number
});

// create mongoose schema
const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    roomId: String,
});

// create mongoose model
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Room = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);

/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('api works');
});

/* GET all users. */
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }
        res.status(200).json(users);
    });
});

/* GET all rooms. */
router.get('/room', function(req, res) {
    Room.find({}, function (err, room) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }
        res.status(200).json(room);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In my mongo data are stored like this :

```
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5903a7ee0e999a5054cc402b"), "mail" : "mail@google.com", "mdp" : "toto", "firstname" : "firstname", "participants" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5903ae7952163fd952970ed5"), "mail" : "mail2@google.com", "mdp" : "toto", "firstname" : "firstname", "participants" : 50 }

> db.room.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59043f280d062a4959b69315"), "roomId" : "6733454" }
```

I search for a long time but to be honest, i don't know why it doesn't work, i also try to put users data into room data and to copy/paste user schema into room schema, but it doesn't work also.

If i put the User model object in router.get room, it works, i get users data, so for me it's not a problem of route.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Mongoose applies a function ([`utils.toCollectionName()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#utils_exports.toCollectionName)) to the name of a model to determine the collection name that Mongoose will use for that model. For a model called `Room`, that collection name will be `rooms`.

However, your collection is called `room` (singular), so there's a mismatch there.

To fix this, you can explicitly specify which collection should be used using the [`collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) schema option:

```
const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  roomId: String,
}, {
  collection : 'room'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the name of your collection is `room`, as in singular. The correct name for the collection is `rooms`, plural.

Mongoose infers from the model name `Room` that there should be a collection named `rooms` in the database. If there isn't, it just fails silently and returns an empty array.

If you simply change the name of your collection in the database from `room` to `rooms`, your code will work.

You can do so with the [renameCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys, it was just that and it was in front of me all this times...

It works perfect with collection rooms and not room